# Is there an online or downloadable "copyable" bible?

Tags: bible, internet

What I mean is a site or file that is designed to be copied on the computer. I.e, no headers, no footnotes, all chapters of a book on one page, preferably with options like verse-per-line and different versions (esv, kjv, etc.).

If this doesn't exist, someone should definitely make it. I frequently copy large portions, sometimes entire books, of the bible for study projects.

The best I've found is biblestudytools.com, which is almost perfect except I can't get rid of headers and there's only 1 chapter per page.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site.  To get an idea of how things work around here, please take the [tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out our [help centre](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and some of our [Meta FAQs](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?mixed=1) like [What makes a good focused question?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question?s=1|51.5118)

Comment: This may be closed as a "shopping question", but it is easy to give a useful answer to it, so I did.

Answer (score 3):

A number of Bible programs have a "copy verses" function with enough flexibility to do what you ask. I agree with Cindy's answer, that E-sword can most likely do it. My own preference is TheWord, available from www.theword.net.

I ran a test with two lines between verses, and headers only at the beginning of each chapter. I didn't try to space the chapter header properly, but I think you will see that you can adjust it to your liking if you try the program. To be sure it was adequate, I verified that it would copy the whole Bible, provided I used a public domain version. I used the American King James Version, abbreviated AKJV in this example:

... snip from Gen 1:1 ...

And they shall bring the glory and honor of the nations into it.

And there shall in no wise enter into it any thing that defiles, neither whatever works abomination, or makes a lie: but they which are written in the Lamb's book of life.

Rev22AKJV

And he showed me a pure river of water of life, clear as crystal, proceeding out of the throne of God and of the Lamb.

In the middle of the street of it, and on either side of the river, was there

... snip rest of Rev 22 ...

TheWord is a Windows program, but is usable on Mac and Linux as well.

Answer (score 2):

You might like e-sword at (I think) esword.com. I think it will meet your needs, from what you've said. Have a look; the basic program and common domain bible resources and translations are free, plus additional resources can be purchased. Also there are independent websources of other bible translations and resourses available (usually free) formatted for the same program.

Answer (score 1):

Project Gutenberg has the entire text of the [King James version](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/7999) in one file (3 different formats). It is free and might serve your needs.